# In librdkafka, dr_cb is executed on produce() thread or on poll() thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, apache-kafka

I have different threads to produce a message to Kafka and other thread which only polls Kafka to check delivery reports or events.

Question is, on which thread will the dr_cb() method be executed? Will it be executed on The original produce thread or the polling thread?

If the dr_cb is called on the original produce thread, will it interrupt the current execution?

Comment: Though I don't know for a fact what it does - and I can't check right now - it's hard to imagine how the library would gain control over the producer thread and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delivery report callback, along with most other callbacks (`log_cb` is an exception), are triggered from the application thread when the application calls `rd_kafka_poll()` or `rd_kafka_flush()`.

This is explained in the [introduction document](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#threads-and-callbacks).